# Is i3 4gb ram ok for ubuntu installation

Tags: software-installation, system, gimp, nodejs, web-development

I want to switch from win to linux. My laptop has i3 and 4gb ram, 500gb hdd. Could you please tell me if ubuntu 20 would run smoothly on it? Will nodejs, vs code, gimp etc run smoothly on it. Please help me out as i am absolutely new to the whole of linux/ubuntu ecosystem and a big thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The only person who can answer this question is you. My definition of "smooth" will not be the same as yours, which means any answer would be incredibly subjective. Download the installation image, write it as a bootable USB, and give it a try. If you think the system is okay, install the OS. Otherwise, try another distribution that requires fewer resources, such as Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu ‍

Comment: I find a lighter weight install works even on systems with more memory. I use Kubuntu which is a middle weight install on desktop with 16GB RAM, that still worked on my old laptop with 1.5GB RAM. Ubuntu would not even install on old laptop. Not speedy but functional. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

Comment: Hello. a good place to start is to know what you are installing. There is not such Ubuntu version as 20.

Comment: matigo is correct and it is also likely the reason why this gets closed. Ubuntu is free so install it and check for yourself if it is smooth by trying all the different flavours.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the system requirements on the official [Ubuntu page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), which says that

- 2 GHz dual-core processor or better
- 4 GB system memory
- 25 GB of free hard drive space
- Internet access is helpful
- Either a DVD drive
  or a USB port for the installer media